Keeping application open when console window is closed
I'm working on a project for a friend and it involves making a program that runs as a background service. Right now I have it starting, and it runs in the background. It has an icon in the service tray as well. The icon's context menu has Show Output and Exit. When Show Output is pressed, it opens a console window (with AllocConsole) that displays the logging information so far and waits for a keypress to close.
If it's closed with a keypress, then everything is fine. But if it's closed with Ctrl+C or by clicking the red X, it will shut down the entire program including the background service. How can I work around this? I do want the console window to be closed, so simply disabling Ctrl+C isn't a viable solution, but the program should still keep running after this console window is closed.
Here's the relevant code:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    // Methods for creating and deleting new consoles
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a system tray icon
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Shield;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon.Text = "Background Service";

        // Handle icon click event
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += (object s, MouseEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                ShowLoggingWindow();
        };

        // Set up context menu
        ContextMenuStrip trayIconMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Show Output");
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Exit");
        trayIconMenuStrip.Items.Add(menuItem1);
        trayIconMenuStrip.Items.Add(menuItem2);

        notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = trayIconMenuStrip;

        // Set up click events
        menuItem1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            ShowLoggingWindow();
        };
        menuItem2.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            Application.Exit();
        };

        ... // other setup

        // Start the message loop
        Application.Run();
    }

    static void ShowLoggingWindow()
    {
        // Allocate a new console window
        AllocConsole();

        // Redirect standard output to the new console window
        Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), Console.OutputEncoding) { AutoFlush = true });

        // Write to the new console window
        ...
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

        // Keep the window open until the user presses a key
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Close the console window
        FreeConsole();
    }

    ...
}

This isn't really my area so I'm not sure where to even start. I can't find any useful information elsewhere online but it could just be that I don't know what exactly to search for.

This question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. It's easy to disable ctrl+c to close, but the main issue is that the program also shuts down when the console window is closed by other means (like by clicking the X as I mentioned in my original post). In fact, I'd prefer to keep Ctrl+C enabled to close the console window, it just needs to not shut down the rest of the program. It's a background service so it needs to stay active. The console window is just to monitor the logs of the program.

I would appreciate some clarification as to why my edits were not sufficient. The linked questions describe how to make ctrl+c not close the console window. However, I want ctrl+c to close the console window, but I want closing the console window to keep the main process open no matter how it's closed. These are completely different things.

OP and Reopen reviewers may consider the following from another stack: https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background
This question is simpler to resolve in the context of an OS-level question than as a programming question.
